# Share onclick function to button components React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to make a generic button in which I pass certain properties as a parameter. one of those properties is the function that must be executed at the time of clicking event.

```
function Boton(props: { name: React.ReactNode , funcion: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (<div className="center-div"><IonButton shape="round" onClick={props.funcion}> {props.name}</IonButton></div>);
}
```

But what I got is:

> JSX attribute) onClick?: ((event:
> React.MouseEvent<HTMLIonButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => void) |
> undefined Type ‘ReactNode’ is not assignable to type ‘((event:
> MouseEvent<HTMLIonButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => void) | undefined’.
> Type ‘null’ is not assignable to type ‘((event:
> MouseEvent<HTMLIonButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => void) |
> undefined’.ts(2322) index.d.ts(1455, 9): The expected type comes from
> property ‘onClick’ which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes
> & Pick<IonButton, “color” | “strong” | “disabled” | “size” | “fill” |
> “mode”

But I do not want a Mouse event because it is going to be a mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are giving `React.ReactNode` type to your function parameter.
You should give it a function  type.

Maybe something like this: `() => void`

Also, I guess your name parameter should be a `String`

Answer (score 1):

The 'function' props to the generic button shouldn't be React.ReactNode.

Iam using arrow function here,

```
const Button = (props: { name: React.ReactNode, onClick: Function}) => 
   (<div className="center-div">
     <IonButton shape="round" onClick={props.onClick}> 
      {props.name}
    </IonButton>
 </div>);
```

And where ever you are defining your generic button, define the name and onClick props.

Hope the above code will solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks. this is what I got: (JSX attribute) onClick?: ((event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLIonButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => void) | undefined
Type 'Function' is not assignable to type '(event: MouseEvent<HTMLIonButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => void'.ts(2322)